# Reading a XML file from resources

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

I have a XML file that I need to parse in the Android SDK.

How can I read the XML file path from resources?

The XML contains:

```
<Book>
<Chapter>
<NO>   1   </NO>
<Text>  My Lord </Text>
</Chapter> 

<Chapter>
<NO>   1   </NO>
<Text>  My Lord </Text>
</Chapter>
</Book>
```

Comment: where are you having the file in raw folder or assets folder?

Comment: I dont know how to add XML file into resources.

Comment: you can put your xml in res/raw or assets folder and then parse it.

Comment: i added the XML file in asserts folder. but how can i parse it?

Comment: As many answers you want. http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=read+xml+from+resources+android#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=active&source=hp&q=android+read+xml+file+from+assets&pbx=1&oq=read+xml+from+asse+android&aq=0b&aqi=g-b2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=318963l319667l0l320812l4l3l0l0l0l1l212l576l0.2.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=40f04f0c97159462&biw=1280&bih=677&safe=on

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put it under `your_project_root\res\xml\` folder. Then you can open it with:

```
Resources res = activity.getResources();
XmlResourceParser xrp = res.getXml(R.xml.your_resId);
```

There is an example on how to use `XmlResourceParser` here:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html

Answer (score 6):

If you have an XML file in the raw folder in your resources then you can read it with the following code:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```

I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 5):

Before parsing xml create one folder inside your resources and put xml file inside that. And try this code.

```
try {
            XmlPullParser xpp=getResources().getXml(R.xml.words);

            while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("word")) {
                        items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                    }
                }

                xpp.next();
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast
                .makeText(this, "Request failed: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }
```