# How to solve error: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

In my app,I've the below code:

```
object FaceDetection {

    private val faceModel = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

    private lateinit var faceCascade: CascadeClassifier

    fun loadModel(activity: Activity) {
        faceCascade = CascadeClassifier(File(activity.filesDir, "das").apply { writeBytes(activity.assets.open(faceModel).readBytes()) }.path)
    }
}
```

Which is fail with the above mentioned error, I saved 2 copies from the `xml` file, one in the `xml` folder and one in `main/java` folder, but none of them is working, where shall I put this file, and how to call it if there is something wrong in my call above?

[image]
**UPDATE**

I tried solving it as:

```
    private fun loadModel(activity: Activity) {
        var res = activity.resources
        faceModel = res.getXml(R.xml.haarcascade_frontalface_default).text
        faceCascade = CascadeClassifier(File(activity.filesDir, "das").apply {
            writeBytes(activity.assets.open(faceModel).readBytes())
        }.path)
    }
```

But got an error:

```sh
res.getXml(R.xml.haarcas…frontalface_default).text must not be null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a XML file from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665712/reading-a-xml-file-from-resources)

Comment: `activity.assets.open(faceModel).readBytes()` is wrong, in that you do not have an asset. [`getXml()` returns an `XmlResourceParser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getXml(int)), and `getText()` on an `XmlResourceParser` does not return the text of the XML. Perhaps you will be better served my moving this XML into [an actual asset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302624/115145) and going back to your original code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create `assets` folder under the `main` folder, and move the file to it, then I was able to read it as:

```
object FaceDetection {

    private val faceModel = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

    private lateinit var faceCascade: CascadeClassifier

    fun loadModel(activity: Activity) {
        faceCascade = CascadeClassifier(File(activity.filesDir, "das").apply { writeBytes(activity.assets.open(faceModel).readBytes()) }.path)
    }
}
```