# Parsing xml in android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, parsing

I have an a folder which contains an xml file and multiple html, css and js files in my assets folder, and I'm trying to parse the xml folder, to be able to show the linked sites to a webview. The thing is, after googling it, I am completely lost. Any help would be appreciated

Down below is the file. Due to size I cut out repeating parts

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="3.0" xml:lang="eng" unique-identifier="pub-id" prefix="rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/#">
   <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
      <dc:title id="title">Business English</dc:title>
      <dc:creator id="creator">John Taylor, Jaff Zeter</dc:creator>
      <dc:language>eng</dc:language>
      <dc:identifier id="pub-id">Business English</dc:identifier>
      <dc:source>Business English</dc:source>
      <meta property="dcterms:modified">2015-02-04T00:00:52Z</meta>
      <dc:date>2014</dc:date>
      <dc:publisher>Express Publishing</dc:publisher>
      <meta property="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta>
      <meta property="rendition:orientation">landscape</meta>
      <meta property="rendition:spread">none</meta>
   </metadata>
   <manifest>
      <item id="toc" properties="nav" href="TOC.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
      <item id="cover" href="cover.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
      <item id="cover-image" properties="cover-image" href="images/BusinessEnglish_cover_epub.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="s001" href="s001-Chapter-001.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
      <item id="s002" properties="scripted" href="s002-Chapter-002.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="17" activityName="Exercise 1" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s003" properties="scripted" href="s003-LessonRunOn-001.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="18" activityName="Exercise 2" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Reading" />
      <item id="s004" properties="scripted" href="s004-LessonRunOn-002.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="19" activityName="Exercise 3" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s005" properties="scripted" href="s005-LessonRunOn-003.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="20" activityName="Exercise 4" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s006" properties="scripted" href="s006-LessonRunOn-004.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="21" activityName="Exercise 5" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Listening" />
      <item id="s007" properties="scripted" href="s007-LessonRunOn-005.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="22" activityName="Exercise 6" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Listening" />
      <item id="s008" properties="scripted" href="s008-LessonRunOn-006.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="23" activityName="Exercise 7" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Speaking" />
      <item id="s009" properties="scripted" href="s009-LessonRunOn-007.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="24" activityName="Exercise 9" moduleId="24" moduleName="Greetings and goodbyes" skillType="Writing" />
      <item id="s010" properties="scripted" href="s010-Chapter-003.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="25" activityName="Exercise 1" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s011" properties="scripted" href="s011-LessonRunOn-008.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="26" activityName="Exercise 2" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Reading" />
      <item id="s012" properties="scripted" href="s012-LessonRunOn-009.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="27" activityName="Exercise 3" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s013" properties="scripted" href="s013-LessonRunOn-010.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="28" activityName="Exercise 4" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s014" properties="scripted" href="s014-LessonRunOn-011.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="29" activityName="Exercise 5" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Reading" />
      <item id="s015" properties="scripted" href="s015-LessonRunOn-012.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="30" activityName="Exercise 6" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Listening" />
      <item id="s016" properties="scripted" href="s016-LessonRunOn-013.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="31" activityName="Exercise 7" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Listening" />
      <item id="s017" properties="scripted" href="s017-LessonRunOn-014.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="32" activityName="Exercise 8" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Speaking" />
      <item id="s018" properties="scripted" href="s018-LessonRunOn-015.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="33" activityName="Exercise 9" moduleId="25" moduleName="Introductions" skillType="Writing" />
      <item id="s019" properties="scripted" href="s019-Chapter-004.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="34" activityName="Exercise 1" moduleId="26" moduleName="Small talk" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s020" properties="scripted" href="s020-LessonRunOn-016.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="35" activityName="Exercise 2" moduleId="26" moduleName="Small talk" skillType="Reading" />
      <item id="s021" properties="scripted" href="s021-LessonRunOn-017.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="36" activityName="Exercise 3" moduleId="26" moduleName="Small talk" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s022" properties="scripted" href="s022-LessonRunOn-018.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="37" activityName="Exercise 4" moduleId="26" moduleName="Small talk" skillType="Vocabulary" />
      <item id="s023" properties="scripted" href="s023-LessonRunOn-019.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" activityId="38" activityName="Exercise 5" moduleId="26" moduleName="Small talk" skillType="Reading" />
      <item id="images-001" href="images/a005_online.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
      <item id="images-002" href="images/audio-controls.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-003" href="images/b1_001_3_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-004" href="images/b1_004_1_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-005" href="images/b1_004_1lessonrunon_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-006" href="images/b1_004_2_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-007" href="images/b1_004_3_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-008" href="images/b1_005_3_1_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-009" href="images/b1_005_4_1_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-010" href="images/b1_005_5_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-011" href="images/b1_006_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-012" href="images/b1_007_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-013" href="images/b1_008_2_001_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-014" href="images/b1_008_3_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-015" href="images/b1_008_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-016" href="images/b1_010_1_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-017" href="images/b1_012_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-018" href="images/b1_013_1_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-019" href="images/b1_014_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-020" href="images/b1_016_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-021" href="images/b1_017_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-022" href="images/b1_018_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-023" href="images/b1_019_1_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-024" href="images/b1_019_2_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-025" href="images/b1_020_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-026" href="images/b1_021_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-027" href="images/b1_022_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-028" href="images/b1_023_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-029" href="images/b1_024_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-030" href="images/b1_025_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-031" href="images/b1_026_new_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-032" href="images/b1_028_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="images-033" href="images/b1_029_online.png" media-type="image/png" />
      <item id="audio-001" href="audio/au_accommodation.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-002" href="audio/au_accomplish.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-003" href="audio/au_account.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-004" href="audio/au_accountant.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-005" href="audio/au_address.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-006" href="audio/au_adopt.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-007" href="audio/au_advantage.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-008" href="audio/au_affordable.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-009" href="audio/au_agm.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-010" href="audio/au_aheadofschedule.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-011" href="audio/au_ambition.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-012" href="audio/au_amenity.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-013" href="audio/au_analyze.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-014" href="audio/au_anonymous.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-015" href="audio/au_anticipate.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-016" href="audio/au_applicant.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-017" href="audio/au_appointment.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-018" href="audio/au_approach.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-019" href="audio/au_approximately.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-020" href="audio/au_arrange.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-021" href="audio/au_assembled.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-022" href="audio/au_assemblyline.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-023" href="audio/au_asset.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-024" href="audio/au_assure.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-025" href="audio/au_atsymbol.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-026" href="audio/au_attachment.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-027" href="audio/au_attentive.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-028" href="audio/au_audience.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-029" href="audio/au_authoritarian.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="audio-030" href="audio/au_autonomy.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg" />
      <item id="video-001" href="video/b01u03communicateinbusinessout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-002" href="video/b01u10howtobuyacomputerout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-003" href="video/b01u14bikingtoworkout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-004" href="video/b01u15essentialinterviewout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-005" href="video/b02u01topcellphonesout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-006" href="video/b02u03returningfaultyproductout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-007" href="video/b02u09businessmeetingetiout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-008" href="video/b03u01greencompanycultureout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="video-009" href="video/b03u05workingtheassemblyout_srt.mp4" media-type="video/mp4" />
      <item id="js-001" href="js/AIEL_StudentsGlossary.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-002" href="js/aie_core.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-003" href="js/aie_explore.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-004" href="js/aie_qaa.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-005" href="js/aie_textsound.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-006" href="js/igp-webapp.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-007" href="js/igp_audio.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-008" href="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-009" href="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-010" href="js/jquery-ui.min.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-011" href="js/popup.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="js-012" href="js/pubsub.js" media-type="text/javascript" />
      <item id="css-001" href="css/BusinessEnglish.css" media-type="text/css" />
      <item id="fonts-001" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-002" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-BlackIt.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-003" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-004" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-BoldIt.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-005" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-006" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-007" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-It.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-008" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-009" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-LightIt.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-010" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-011" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-012" href="fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt.otf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-013" href="fonts/URWGothicL-Book.ttf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
      <item id="fonts-014" href="fonts/URWGothicL-BookObli.ttf" media-type="application/vnd.ms-opentype" />
   </manifest>
   <spine page-progression-direction="ltr">
      <itemref idref="cover" linear="yes" properties="rendition:page-spread-center" />
      <itemref idref="s001" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s002" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s003" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s004" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s005" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s006" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s007" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s008" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s009" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s010" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s011" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s012" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s013" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s014" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s015" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s016" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s017" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s018" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s019" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s020" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s021" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s022" linear="yes" />
      <itemref idref="s023" linear="yes" />
   </spine>
</package>
```

Comment: Here's an XML parsing lib I used a few times: https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml. But I don't understand what is your problem exactly.

Comment: I would think he is trying to parse the content of this .xml file that's part of the Android project. But this is just an assumption.

Comment: Exactly what @Marton said

Comment: I am not sure that this is the best approach for what you're trying to achieve, but to answer your question: @Mieczkoni is correct, use an XML parsing library, you'll have to provide the path to you xml to the parser and you should be set. Check out the link, I believe this is what you'd like to do.

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665712/reading-a-xml-file-from-resources